When editing info, should the edit page have a back arrow or close tag?
My thinking is the close tag makes more sense, since it minimises the chance of a user accidentally going back and losing progress.


The context is not clear. What does 'losing progress' mean? Do you mean the edit happens over multiple pages?

In this instance, losing progress would mean the user doesn't save the new number which they may have chosen when editing.

I think it depends on how the page opens. If the page is swiping through from the right side, then I would use a back button. If the page in coming in from the bottom of the page, then the close tag makes more sense.
